# How can I create a file as well as missing dirs along the path in linux system programatically?

Tags: linux, create-directory

I want to create a file on linux system in my program, say /a/b/c/test, currently I only have dir /a exist and I want to do it in my program, is there any function that can create file as well as missing dirs (that is, create b/c/test) in one deal? open, fopen, mkdir all seem can't work if there are missing dirs along the path. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `strace mkdir -p a/b/c`:

```
mkdir("a", 0751)                        = 0
open("a", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 3
fchdir(3)                               = 0
close(3)                                = 0
mkdir("b", 0751)                        = 0
open("b", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 3
fchdir(3)                               = 0
close(3)                                = 0
mkdir("c", 0751)                        = 0
```

In other words, you have to call `mkdir()` yourself, in a loop per directory, then create the file. This is how the `mkdir` exe does it (in C). Why not run the `mkdir -p /a/b/c` command with `execve`? With C stuff set up for the call properly, of course.

Comment: Ok, I guess this is the only way.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I gave up on C, meself.

Comment: This will not create a file c but a folder with the name c

Answer (score 3):

I think you need two commands:

```
$ mkdir -p /a/b/c/ && touch /a/b/c/test
```

Comment: @wangshuaijie Which programming language?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you will have to be satisfied with a two-step process:

```
mkdir -p /a/b/c
touch /a/b/c/test
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/) (the lowest level library of Gtk, which can be used independently) you could just call [g_mkdir_with_parents](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.32/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-mkdir-with-parents) to make all the directories (like the `mkdir -p` command does)